# AdMob Ads - Main Thread Checker error in log

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I just added AdMob into my `UIViewController`, and when I run the app, it freezes for a few seconds, and then this shows up:

```
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 8093, TID: 1911410, Thread name: com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000198a9b894 <redacted> + 56
5   CoreMotion                          0x000000019f321040 CoreMotion + 307264
6   CoreMotion                          0x000000019f321574 CoreMotion + 308596
7   CoreMotion                          0x000000019f321484 CoreMotion + 308356
8   CoreMotion                          0x000000019f352c64 CoreMotion + 511076
9   CoreMotion                          0x000000019f352cc4 CoreMotion + 511172
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001998324fc <redacted> + 28
11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000199831de0 <redacted> + 276
12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019982d0e4 <redacted> + 2324
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019982c4b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000019982d21c CFRunLoopRun + 84
15  CoreMotion                          0x000000019f3525fc CoreMotion + 509436
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001994a7974 <redacted> + 132
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001994a78d0 _pthread_start + 52
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001994afddc thread_start + 4
```

Any tips?

Comment: Please share your code for better explanation. But I think you're doing it in the main thread. -Main Thread for only UI actions. Otherwise UI will freeze.- You should do it in background thread. `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { ... }`

Comment: @EmreCiftci Solved. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @KurtNobel. I'm very happy for my answer can solved the problem. If it's work for you please mark as accepted. Enjoy.

Comment: @EmreCiftci Can't since this is a comment, post it as a answer to my question, and I will be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your problem is this process is in the Main Thread . Main Thread for only UI action. Otherwise UI will freeze.
- You should do it in background thread.

  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
      // Your code
  }

Enjoy.